# JSF tag for disabling a checkbox on selecting a dropdown without using JavaScript

Tags: jsf-2

I have a dropdown and checkbox in my page and if we select a dropdown then the checkbox has to be disabled. We should not use JavaScript for this. I am new to JSF. Is there a way by using JSF. Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `<f:ajax>` which executes on change of the dropdown and updates the checkbox whereby its `disabled` attribute checks if the dropdown's value is not empty.

E.g.:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
    <f:ajax render="checkbox" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" disabled="#{not empty bean.selectedItem}" />
```

That's basically all.

Please note that this uses *under the covers* still JavaScript for the job! The only difference is that you don't need to manually write any line of JavaScript code, instead JSF autogenerates the necessary JS code for you.